# Filtering in pandas Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, nan

I have a column in the data frame from which I filter using loc[((df['id']>1000) and it works. But I would like to add & where 'id' is also "NaN". How can I write such an 'and' with two conditions, i.e. id>1000 & id==Nan

I tried ==Nan, =='Nan', isnan but the result I get is no lines where Id==Nan

Comment: use pandas `isna`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isna.html

Comment: You can always use two passes, first with first filter, then use 2nd filter. E.g.
`rslt_df = dataframe[dataframe['Percentage'] > 70][dataframe['Age'] < 20.0]`

.dropna() can be considered as well.

Notes: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()!